# Issue while creating docker image on apple M1

Tags: docker, apple-m1, arm64

I am trying to create a docker image on Apple M1 machine. But it shows some issues at one step(image is created though, but container doesnt run for it):

```
COPY bin/linux/tempo-arm64 /tempo
```

Error is:

```
High severity vunerabilities were found in this layer
```

Any workaround for this?